# Cropping rotated image with same aspect ratio

Tags: python, image-processing, rotation, crop

How can I find out the width and height of the final image when the input image is rotated by given amount of degrees and then cropped to avoid any non-image areas while maintaining the original image aspect ratio.

example:
[image: example]

Comment: This is an excellent question and I too wouldn't mind knowing the answer, but would this be better suited for Math Stack Exchange?

Comment: maybe. I though maybe somebody knows a trick in Python PIL so posted here.

Comment: Fingers crossed. I'm trying...

Comment: I actually just figured out how to do it. Turns out was pretty simple. Writing solution now.

Comment: Oh thank god. I was getting ready to abandon ship when I realized my equation depended on knowing a variable I was trying to solve for in the first place!

Comment: taking a bit of time to type the answer. im trying to make all diagrams...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

- Red rectangle is original image with original aspect ratio.
- `W/t` rectangle (enclosed by green and yellow triangles) is rotated
  image aspect ratio with `extend=True`.

Here is how to get the `w` and `h`.

```
image = Image.open(...)
rotated = image.rotate(degrees, Image.BICUBIC, True)

aspect_ratio = float(image.size[0]) / image.size[1]
rotated_aspect_ratio = float(rotated.size[0]) / rotated.size[1]
angle = math.fabs(degrees) * math.pi / 180

if aspect_ratio < 1:
    total_height = float(image.size[0]) / rotated_aspect_ratio
else:
    total_height = float(image.size[1])

h = total_height / (aspect_ratio * math.sin(angle) + math.cos(angle))
w = h * aspect_ratio
```

Now the rotated image can be cropped in the center with `w`x`h` dimensions to
get the final image.

Comment: If `aspect ration = a = w/h` then wouldn't it be `w = a / h` not `w = h * a`?

Comment: You multiply both sides by h hence ha=hw/h but h/h is 1 so is canceled.

Comment: Found a mistake in the code: You need to take the absolute values of the sine and cosine, otherwise it will break for rotations > 90°

Answer (score 1):

[image]

## Definitions:

- W<sub>0</sub> and H<sub>0</sub> are the original rectangle's width and height
- D<sub>0</sub> is the diagonal (hypotenuse) of the original rectangle
- W<sub>1</sub> and H<sub>1</sub> are the padded width and height of the rotated rectangle
- W<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub> are the width and height of the target rectangle
- D<sub>2</sub> is the diagonal (hypotenuse) of the target rectangle
- E is complicated and transient
- You probably want to precompute sin(A), cos(A), and tan(A) as they are used repeatedly

## Computing W<sub>1</sub> and H<sub>1</sub>:

These are made up of two components, the two triangle sides that make up each length

- W<sub>1</sub> = W<sub>0</sub>*cos(A) + H<sub>0</sub>*sin(A)
- H<sub>1</sub> = H<sub>0</sub>*cos(A) + W<sub>0</sub>*sin(A)

## Computing W<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>:

- E = W<sub>0</sub> / (1 + tan(A) / W<sub>0</sub> * H<sub>0</sub>)
- W<sub>2</sub> = E / tan(A)
- H<sub>2</sub> = W<sub>2</sub> / W<sub>0</sub> * H<sub>0</sub>

## As Python:

```
W0 = # original rectangle width
H0 = # original rectangle height
cosA = cos(A)
sinA = sin(A)
tanA = tan(A)
W1 = W0 * cosA + H0 * sinA
H1 = H0 * cosA + W0 * sinA
E = W0 / (1 + tanA / W0 * H0)
W2 = E / tanA       # requested width
H2 = W2 / W0 * H0   # requested height
```

Disclaimer: this is all untested

---

Edit: by request, my best guess of what I meant by E:

```
r0 = w2/h2
h2 = (w0-e1) / sin(A)
h2 = e1/ cos(A) / r0
(w0-e1) / sin(A) = e1/ cos(A) / r0
x = cos(A) / sin(A)
e1 = w0 * x / (1/r0 + x)
```

E was the horizontal component of w2, extended through the line a+b. Then it was about computing what was `a` vs `b`, using the aspect ratio and sin/cos to figure that out. Terms cancelled, voices were raised, and that's what I ended up with.

Comment: What is E? Maybe a wiki link.

Comment: No link. I derived this myself and E was a dimension I needed. I'll update the post with an image. It was surprisingly different from yours!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing smething trivial here but I'm still not following what is e. Maybe in the evening I'll give this another try.

Comment: -1: This can't possibly be correct: dividing by tan(alpha). tan(epsilon) = epsilon. Tiny rotations cause you divide by a tiny number, causing completely wrong widths, according to your formula.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns coords of this block

[returned box - is the coords of this block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhRiy.png)

```
from PIL import Image
def cropp_rotated(image, degrees):
    x, y = image.size
    cosA = abs(math.cos(math.radians(degrees)))
    sinA = abs(math.sin(math.radians(degrees)))

    a = x * cosA 
    b = x * sinA

    relation = a / (a + b)
    right_indent1 = a - x * relation * cosA

    relation = b / (a + b)
    bottom_ident1 = b - x * relation *sinA


    c = y * cosA 
    d = y * sinA

    relation = c / (c + d)
    right_indent2 = c - y * relation * cosA

    relation = d / (c + d)
    bottom_ident2 = d - y * relation *sinA

    right_indent = max(right_indent1, right_indent2)
    top_indent = max(bottom_ident1, bottom_ident2)

    #size of rotated image:
    w_rotated = x * cosA + y * sinA
    h_rotated = y * cosA + x * sinA


    box = (
    int(right_indent), 
    int(top_indent), 
    int(w_rotated - right_indent), 
    int(h_rotated - top_indent))

    return box
```

I import PIL only for get image real size.
You can not import PIL, instead of this you can get image size any other way.